# Graphql Codegen adds an extra property for my custom scalars

Tags: graphql, graphql-codegen

I just recently added the `typescript-resolvers` plugin to my codegen config, and while it does what I need, it seems to also add my custom scalars to the `ResolversTypes`.

The issue is that it seems to add an extra `['output']` property to these scalars. For example; I end up getting an error:

```
Property 'output' does not exist on type 'X'
```

Example:

```
// generated.ts
/** All built-in and custom scalars, mapped to their actual values */
export type Scalars = {
  ID: string;
  String: string;
  Boolean: boolean;
  Int: number;
  Float: number;
  DataURL: any;
  Date: any;
  DateTime: any;
  Email: any;
  JSON: any;
  PhoneNumber: any;
};

// ....

/** Mapping between all available schema types and the resolvers types */
export type ResolversTypes = {
  Boolean: ResolverTypeWrapper<Scalars['Boolean']['output']>;
  ID: ResolverTypeWrapper<Scalars['ID']['output']>;
  Float: ResolverTypeWrapper<Scalars['Float']['output']>;
  Int: ResolverTypeWrapper<Scalars['Int']['output']>;
  PhoneNumber: ResolverTypeWrapper<Scalars['PhoneNumber']['output']>; // <-- this one weirdly doesn't throw an error?
  String: ResolverTypeWrapper<Scalars['String']['output']>;

/** Mapping between all available schema types and the resolvers parents */
export type ResolversParentTypes = {
  Boolean: Scalars['Boolean']['output'];
  DataURL: Scalars['DataURL']['output']; // <-- this one also doesn't throw an error
  Date: Scalars['Date']['output']; // <-- this one also doesn't throw an error
  DateTime: Scalars['DateTime']['output']; // <-- this one also doesn't throw an error
  Float: Scalars['Float']['output'];
  ID: Scalars['ID']['output'];
  Int: Scalars['Int']['output'];
  String: Scalars['String']['output'];
```

Am I missing something from my config? Ideally I want to remove this weird `['output']` property